# @Transaction not working across multiple methods in different services

Tags: spring-boot, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

We have a spring boot app using JDBCTemplate and have 4 service calls (each from a different service) that each have updates to the DB.  When we annotate the wrapping method with @Transaction each individual service call is transactional, but an exception in the 3rd service call does not roll back what was done in the first 2. (Or an exception in the 2nd doesn't roll back the first one etc...)

Clarification: The exceptions are runtime

EDIT: We have tried with @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) which seems like it should persist the transaction across the calls, but it still isn't working.

SOLUTION:  There was a truncate table in one of the services which ends the transaction.  We will changed that to delete from and everything is now working transactionally.

Comment: is the Exception checked or Runtime?

Comment: Runtime Exception

Comment: well this is the part of the documentation you should be reading then: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation

Comment: Is there any information in the exceptions you're getting regarding spring and transactions? Have you enabled DEBUG logging in org.springframework.transaction package? Can you paste related to spring transactions log messages when the problem happens?

Comment: We are not getting any exceptions from the actual transaction management.  The only exceptions currently are the ones we are purposely throwing to test the transaction.

Comment: Can you post some code?